# Counting Existing ID's in a different table - laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have two items in a table called `products` with id's `1 and 2`. There is a table called `invite` which has foreign key `product_id` for `products`.

In my controller below, i am trying to count the number of product id's that is existing in the `invite` table.

eg

```
Product            invite

id    name        id   token     product_id  user_id
1     cal         1    ..d          1           2
2     del         2    dd..         2           2
3     mac         3    ..gh4        2           2
```

As above, id's `1 and 2` exist in the invite table. meaning the total count is 2 (although product id `2` appears twice.

When i run my code below, i get a count of `1` instead of `2`. What could i be missing out, please?

**NB: in this case, i am user just one user**

**Controller**

```
public function dashboard()
{
    $products = Products::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
        ->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->get();

    $get_products_id = [];

    foreach($products as $product){

        $get_products_id[] = $product->id;
    }

    $implode_data = implode(',',$get_products_id);


    $count_existing_products = 
        Invite::where('product_id',$implode_data)
            ->where('user_id', Auth::user()- >id)->get()->count();

    return view('dashboard', compact('count_existing_products'));

}
```

**View**

```
<h1>{{count_existing_products}}}</h1>
```

Comment: You also filter by `user_id`, maybe it is the case? I also suppose that passing imploded string works not as you expected.

Comment: Using `user_id` in where condition as well, but there is no `user_id` shown in structure for invite table above.

Comment: @u_mulder, i am using just one user in this case. check update pleas

Comment: @LovepreetSingh, please check the update

Comment: One suggestion you can use **$products->pluck('id')->all()** intsead of this **$get_products_id = [];

    foreach($products as $product){

        $get_products_id[] = $product->id;
    }**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `WHERE IN` clause laravel uses special `whereIn()` method where you pass **array**, not **string**. So, your query becomes:

```
Invite::whereIn('product_id', $get_products_id)
    ->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
    ->distinct()         // added `distinct` call to get distinct values
    ->get()
    ->count();
```

If `distinct` does not work, try to `groupBy`:

```
Invite::whereIn('product_id', $get_products_id)
    ->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
    ->groupBy('product_id')
    ->get()
    ->count();
```

Comment: @LovepreetSingh OP needs `2` as a result, not `3` according to table data. Did you read a question __carefully__?

Comment: @LovepreetSingh because filtering is done with `WHERE IN` where product ids are `1` and `2`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use implode. you can use whereIn instead of where.

```
Invite::whereIn('product_id',$get_products_id)
              ->where('user_id', Auth::user()- >id)->get()->count();
```